# Update document in library using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom

I have a document library and I would like to update the metadata(columns) of a document using JSOM.  I thought the following would work but it works just on custom list.

```
 var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                            var customLibrary = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Shared Documents');
                            var listItem = customList.getItemById(itemID);

                            /*Set the value and update*/
                            listItem.set_item('Project_0020_Number', prjNum);
                            listItem.update();

                            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                            function(){ 
                                                                            /*Need to change this to show on the page*/
                                                                            alert('Updated'); 
                                            }, 

                                            function(sender, args){ alert('Error: ' + args.get_message()); });
                                            }

                                            function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                                                            alert('Request failed. '+args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a solution to update a document library using JSOM so I went searching for another solution that can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery#code-example-2-upload-a-file-in-the-same-domain-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery) using REST API and jquery.

After the document was uploaded, I was able to modify the code in the link and update the metadata like so

```
"var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}','<internal column name>':'{3}'}}",
itemMetadata.type, newName, newName,<column data>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have not posted the entire code. However, with the code that you have posted, there's some issue with the parenthesis closing. You have not closed `ctx.executeQueryAsync(` correctly.

Also, by default, the title of `Shared Documents` document library is 'Documents'. Have modified the code now.

Below is a sample working code modified from your code:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var customList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
var listItem = customList.getItemById(itemID);

/*Set the value and update*/
listItem.set_item('Project_0020_Number', prjNum);
listItem.update();

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    /*Need to change this to show on the page*/
    alert('Updated'); 
},function(sender, args){
    alert('Request failed. '+args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```

Comment: My apologies.  I meant to say "Custom List" and not Library.  The code above works on a list but not a document library.  I will make the change to the original question.

Comment: I will still try your code though on my library

Comment: Here's the error I get "Request failed. List 'Shared Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'http://isogunro.com/nrm. undefined"

Comment: change the line as `ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');` and check

Comment: Any luck after you modified the code ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work because I'm not using a custom list but a document library.